# CharSequence ArrayList to charSequence casting

Tags: java, android

There is problem of class casting. Please tell me how to cast this. I want to this `ArrayList<CharSequence>` in my `CharSequence[]` named `Contacts`.

`java.lang.ClassCastException` (in Android):

```
CharSequence[] Contacts;
List<CharSequence> contacts = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();


Contacts = (CharSequence[]) contacts.toArray();

for(CharSequence p : contacts) {
    Log.i("log_tag", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" + p);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Contacts = contacts.toArray(new CharSequence[contacts.size()]);
```

Although, I would advise you to rename `Contacts` to something else, perhaps `contactsArray`. Two reasons for this: **1)** Java variable names generally start with a lower-case letter. **2)** You have another variable named `contacts`, defining a second to be `Contacts` will make the code much harder to read and understand since the two names differ *only* by the case of the first letter.

---

Relevant documentation:

- [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 3):

`toArray()` returns an array of type `Object[]`. And `Object[]` and `CharSequence[]` are different types. If you want an array of `CharSequence`, you must use the following code:

```
contactArray = contacts.toArray(new CharSequence[contacts.size()]);
```

See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) for more details.

Note that `Contacts` violates the Java naming conventions, and that having two variables, one named `contacts` and the other named `Contacts`, is really a bad idea (unless you want your code to be as unreadable as possible).